# Help solving a math puzzle table

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

[image: Logical Math Puzzle]

I am struggling to find the answer.

Here is the source: [math logic puzzle phone app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.intellect.brain.math.logical.puzzle).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the answer is

> $66$

because

> the second row is actually the same as the first row, divide all numbers by 6 on the second row,

and you will get

> 13,10,4,?

if you notice the only difference is

> 1,

and the answer would be

> $66$